# Is there a way to cache WordPress that does not loads core?

Tags: cache

Cache is great, but still, testing my application with Blackfire, I saw that even the cached version consumes 43mb of memory, mostly because of WordPress Core load. Is there a way to cache a WordPress website without loading it's core?

Probably, some kind of PHP cache, non-related to WordPress?

Comment: There are many plugins that do this. WP Super Cache,  WP Rocket, W3 Total Cache, WP Fastest Cache, and Cache Enabler, to name just a few.

Comment: @JacobPeattie But all plugins loads the core, no?

Comment: Only if a page hasn't been cached yet (and depending on your settings, WP Super Cache has an option that does load core). Also keep in mind that any AJAX requests will need to load WordPress.